# How to log X-Amzn-Request-id when invoking a lambda? (aws-sdk)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-step-functions

I see that when we invoke a lambda, there is an x-amzn-request-id for that execution:

```
  "resourceType": "lambda",
  "resource": "invoke",
  "output": {
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST",
    "Payload": {
      "recordsReady": false
    },
    "SdkHttpMetadata": {
      "AllHttpHeaders": {
        "X-Amz-Executed-Version": [
          "$LATEST"
        ],
        "x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length": [
          "0"
        ],
        "Connection": [
          "keep-alive"
        ],
        "x-amzn-RequestId": [ <-------------------
          "0b1198a6-2ed8-485b-b5f6-6c086ff192a1"
        ],
```

How would we log out that request id from the lambda using aws-sdk? Is it even possible?

Comment: Unrelated to this question, but I am not sure why you closed [question 75805784](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75805784/regex-to-match-city-name-with-underscores#), but I was in the process of suggesting the following approach: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/6kut08s4/)

Answer (score 0):

context object has a couple of useful properties. One of the mis 'aws_request_id' (for python, but other sdks have it too): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html
That's supposed to give you the request id for the invocation request. I would check that and log it out. E.g.:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(context.aws_request_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! do you know if there is something like this for javascript?

Comment: @RJK I have not used other SDKs but I see this node.js, hope it helps: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-context.html

Answer (score 0):

you could do this in JS either by

- using `context` object, which is the most common way. `context` is passed as the second argument in the handler function:

```
    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
        console.log(`X-Amzn-Request-Id: ${context.awsRequestId}`);
        ...
    }
```

- using `process.env`

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("X-Amzn-Request-Id: " + process.env.AWS_REQUEST_ID);
    // rest of your code
}
```